# How to remove newly created item version if there is no change with previous version in sitecore programmatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-workflow

I am creating version of item on lock & edit button. I want to remove that version if author does not change any value of that version while check in version. I would like to compare versions and delete newly created version if there is no change while check in item version.

Note: No workflow is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ItemSaving event you can get the list of changes in the item.
Here is some sample code to get the idea:

```
protected void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var newItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
        Item originalItem = newItem.Database.GetItem(newItem.ID, newItem.Language, newItem.Version);
    var differences = FindDifferences(newItem, originalItem);    
} 

private List<string> FindDifferences(Item newItem, Item originalItem)
    {
        newItem.Fields.ReadAll();
        IEnumerable<string> fieldNames = newItem.Fields.Select(f => f.Name);
        return fieldNames
          .Where(fieldName => newItem[fieldName] != originalItem[fieldName])
          .ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open item in Content Editor
2. Click on Versions tab
3. Click on Compare button on Versions chunk
   As result you will see dialog with ability to compare 2 versions. If you don't detect any changes then you can remove newly created version.
   [image]
   P.S. Screenshot is from 7.2 version, but 8+ version have pretty the same way to compare versions.

Comment: Thanks for input but my question was how we can do it programmatically